# Как выбрать, в какой папке появляется ssh-пользователь в Debian?

Tags: debian

Есть `vps`-сервер, где находится папка `user1`, доступ к которой имеет одноимённый пользователь. При попытке попытке подключиться к серверу по `openssh`, человек попадает в домашнюю папку. Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь появлялся в отведённой ему папке и не мог покидать её пределы?

Comment: Изменить текущую рабочую директорию в начале сессии можно в `bashrc` (или в конфиге используемой оболочки). А вот по поводу _не мог покидать её пределы_ стоит уточнить, какая задача решается?

Comment: чрутить его надо

Answer (score 1):

Документация на это дело https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/chroot-ssh-env.en.html

В 2х словах: нужно создать корень с минимальным набором програм, нужно включить чрут в пам.